# Is is possible to make property as primary key in model Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Currently I'm an inexperienced newcomer in Django and developing API endpoint using this framework

- `A` class contains a property with custom id as below. When POST a new `A`, `custom_id` is generated automatically from default `id` in Django e.g. 'A00001', 'A00002', 'A00003', ...

```
    class A(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        
       @property
        def custom_id(self):
            return '{}{:05d}'.format('A', self.pk)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

I would like to use `custom_id` as primary key to this model instead of default `id`. If so, I wanna use `custom_id` for POST/PATCH/UPDATE/DELETE request as well

Is it possible to achieve that and how to modify the class? Thanks.

*Note: `custom_id` is a `string` type, not `integer`. I know it's a bad idea to use `string` type for primary key but please feel free to skip it for a moment.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key

Comment: I read it, but it's for `model field` instead of `model property` and it cannot be applied in my case.
Please don't hesitate to correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Model field is representation of  database field, property is not. Primary key can only be set on field

Comment: Got it, it seems impossible to set primary key for property.
Thank you so much.